# PyCharm closes all tabs when PyQt application is closed

Tags: pycharm, pyqt5

I am writing a program with PyQt using PyCharm. Everytime I run the program and then close the window, PyCharm closes all the tabs that I previously opened. I would like to keep them open.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my files were on a network drive. When I move them to a local drive, the tabs stay open as expected. I don't know if it is a bug...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you work on Windows: What helped in my case was mapping the network folder to a network drive.